# How to return the SUM of all Array Lengths in an Object?

Tags: javascript

The function should take an object where all values are Arrays and return the amount of items in all the Arrays combined together.  Here's an example problem:

ex. of an object where the return value should be 3...

```
var obj = {
  arr1: ['val', 'another val'],
  arr2: ['another val']
}
```

I'm assuming the easiest way would be to use a reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a *reduce* operation would suffice

```js
var obj = {
  arr1: ['one', 'two'],
  arr2: ['three']
}

const count = Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, val) =>
  sum + (Array.isArray(val) ? val.length : 0), 0)
  
console.info(count)
```

This iterates the object values and if the value is an array, its `length` is added to the accumulator.